# How to get know when app removed from background?

Tags: android, android-service, android-preferences, android-background

I have some tasks which is running in service. I need it to be running even if the app goes in to background. Its working fine. The problem is, How do I know When my app is removed from background?? In this scenario, I cannot stop my service and which leads to crash. Anybody please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think this way you can prevent to stop background service,
In your Service class you need to return START_STICKY in onStartCommand;

Like this,

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If someone try to force stop service from background process, then android automatically restart your service with START_STICKY.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Your answer Helped me partially.. It helps me to avoid crash, But It doesnt show a way to call the revert action when the task is not completed and service finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think implementing the `onDestroy()` method in your main class from where you are binding the Service can help

Comment: Can you test this - you *think*? Will it or won't it? :)

Comment: I tested it it is working but is a bit unstable for production purposes